# How to set a default pointtype to use in all plots in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

Is there a way to set a default `pointtype` in gnuplot so that all linespoints plots are drawn with little +'s as points, without having to add `pointtype 1` to all graphs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set for [i=1:N] linetype i pointtype 1
```

Where N is some integer larger than the maximum number of plots you are likely to have in a single `plot` or `splot` command.